# Function with two parameters

Tags: javascript

I am doing a task that is required to add, list and delete todos. It will keep asking you with a prompt question what action you would like to take. When you want to list all the items that you have been added in the console, it is done this way:

```
function listTodos(){
    todos.forEach(function(todo, i){
        console.log(i + ": " + todo);   
    }); 
}
```

My question is, how does the function understand which one of the parameters should be the index (the number) and which one should be the todo?

Comment: Because that's the order they're passed in? See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach: `callback(currentValue, index, array)`.

Comment: you need to pass the parameter in order of syntax array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)

Comment: You just need to see the syntax of forEach:
array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)

Answer (score 1):

These are already defined in javascript you need to take a look at the [documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array
>   element.

**Syntax**

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
 //your iterator 
}[, thisArg]);
```

For more information go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

**Parameters**

**callback**
Function to execute for each element, taking three arguments:

- **currentValue** The current element being processed in the array.
- **index**
  The index of the current element being processed in the array.
- **array**
  The array that forEach() is being applied to.
- **thisArg** 
  Value to use as this(i.e reference Object) when executing callback.

Answer (score 0):

That is predefined in the prototype of the `forEach` function. The first parameter is `currentValue` and second one is `index`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example